# Predict function for multiple linear regression

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a predict function for a homework problem where it takes the dot products of a `matrix(x)` and a `vector(y)` and inserts them into a numpy array

```py
def predict(x, y):
    y_hat = np.empty
    for j in range(len(y)):
        y_hat[i] = np.dot(x, y)
    return y_hat
```

There is an error message on `y_hat[i] = np.dot(x,y)`

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in the code:

1. `numpy.empty()` is a method which get arguments for the shape. Here, you must define it as `np.empty([len(y), len(x)])` (if `x` is matrix and `y` is a vector,`np.dot(x, y)` results a vector with length `len(x)`). It produces a placeholder for `np.dot()` resulted arrays.
2. variable `i` is not defined.

so:

```
def predict(x, y):
    y_hat = np.empty([len(y), len(x)])
    for j in range(len(y)):
        y_hat[j] = np.dot(x, y)
    return y_hat
```